# JavaScript program to randomly generate a single digit number (0,1,…9) one hundred times and output how many 0s,1s, 2s,….9s were generated

Tags: javascript, loops

How to write a JavaScript program to randomly generate a single digit number (0,1,…9) one hundred times and output how many 0s,1s, 2s,….9s were generated.

I can generate a hundred numbers (see below) but can't figure out how to sort them into counters

```
<script>
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
        document.write(num);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: Use an array and count the numbers in there.

Comment: Is that your homework ?

Comment: Side note: The code you have is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (unless you have declarations you haven't shown)..

Comment: That is the exact problem to count how many 0s,1s,2s and so on are randomly generated.

Comment: I understand an array would probably be better, but I barely understand javaScript and am trying to learn so wanted to take it one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the number of each number in an array where each index represents its corresponding number (i.e. the `0`th index will contain the number of `0`s generated) and then increment the number in the array each time it comes up from the `Math.random`.

```
var numOfEachNumber = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    numOfEachNumber[num]++; // Increment the value of the index of the number
                            // that was generated
    document.write(num);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.write(i + ': ' + numOfEachNumber[i]);
}
```

Comment: You probably mean numOfEachNumber[i].

Comment: I just wanted the output so I edited the last line to: document.write(i + "'s " + numOfEachNumber[i],"<p>");

Comment: I would like the output to be 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 with the total number underneath each number?

Comment: @Shawn the `<p>` tag should be used as a block tag like this: `<p>content of paragraph</p>`. If you want the output to be underneath each number, I recommend looking int creating a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Answer (score 1):

You could count frequencies with a *counter*-object.

```
var counter = {};

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 1)
{
  num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  counter[num] = (counter[num]) ? (counter[num]) += 1 : counter[num] = 1;
}

print = function(x) { console.log(x + ": " + counter[x]); };

Object.keys(counter).forEach(print);
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bp8ndhgz/) is the Fiddle to play with.